# Do quantum channels satisfy $\Phi(0)=0$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, quantum-operation

Assume $\Phi$ is a quantum channel, which is a CPTP map. Does the following equality holds and why?
\begin{align}
\Phi(0) = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: What do you mean by 0? A quantum channel describes the evolution of density matrices, which by the axioms of quantum mechanics should have unit trace. If you are just seeing it as a CPTP map for operators, I guess that 0 might be the null matrix, which would essentially fulfil what you state since $\sum_k E_k 0 E_k^\dagger = 0$ trivially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any linear function between any two vector spaces preserves the zero, so yes, any quantum map (and thus also any CPTP map) sends 0 to 0. Note that here "0" means the operator $\mathbb{C}^n\ni v\mapsto 0\in\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Just to add, the proof is quite immediate. It's linear so $\Phi(\alpha A+\beta B) = \alpha \Phi(A) + \beta \Phi(B)$. So we have $\Phi(0) = \Phi(A + (-A)) = \Phi(A) - \Phi(A) = 0$.